# How to handle csv download prompt through a post request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a servlet (java) returning a csv file. So in my controller I send a post request,

def handleCsvRequest

response = RestClient.post theUrlPathTotheServlet queryParams

end

Now how do I handle the response so that it prompts the user to download this csv file. I know you can do this via a form and hidden Iframe but i'd like to do it through rails.  I am looking through fastercsv but i am not finding great examples. Many thanks.

I have tried the following:

i have tried the following

```
 csv_string = RestClient.post url, json, :content_type => :json
 csv_file = CSV.generate do |csv|
   csv << [csv_string]
 end

 send_data csv_file,  :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', :disposition => "attachment; filename=report.csv"
```

but i don't get prompt for a file download? any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use send_file or send_data to send the csv data back to the browser.

A typical example of `send_data` is something along the lines:

```
csv_data = CSV.generate do
  # block to generate CSV text
end

send_data csv_data, :filename => 'your_data.csv'
```

A typical example of `send_file` is

```
@csv_filename ="#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/your_data.csv"
send_file @csv_filename, :filename => "your_data.csv"
```

This should work in development. If this does not work in production, and you are using an Apache server,
you have to comment out the following line in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried the following

...
     csv_string = RestClient.post url, json, :content_type => :json
     csv_file = CSV.generate do |csv|
       csv << [csv_string]
     end

     send_data csv_file,  :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', :disposition => "attachment; filename=frequency-report.csv"

but i don't get prompt for a file download? any ideas?

Comment: I have never given that many options, so I have edited my answer and added some examples that should normally just work.

Comment: yea I've tried it those options as well and it still doesn't work. I get a status 200 and on errors in the logs..I actually get a "Data sent.." log from the ActionController in the development.log but still no prompt to download a file.  I'll keep investigating. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do have a look at

1> http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/ - For Documenation

2> http://supriya-surve.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-fastercsv-to-import-data.html - As an e.g.

Comment: From the question I understand that the csv file is received from a servlet, and then needs to be sent to the browser. So imho the problem is not generating the csv file.